# NPM code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN with Kaspersky on Mac

Tags: macos, npm, kaspersky

This is getting me crazy. Using Kaspersky Internet Security on Mac doesn't allow me to use `npm install` as the error SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN always pops up when Kaspersky is running.

I tried to add the `strict-ssl false` and adding npm's registry, but that doesn't work either.

Anyone got a clue on how to fix it? The problem seems to be coming from the certificate added by Kaspersky in the Keychain.

Comment: By the way, disabling Kaspersky makes npm run like a champ again.

Comment: I'm not sure how you've installed npm, although maybe try `npm install npm -g --ca=null` followed by `npm config set ca=""`.

Comment: There's also `sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain /path/to/kaspersky.crt` perhaps.

Comment: I installed npm through nvm